# Object oriented design pattern for create more objects in a class(c#)

Tags: asp.net, oop, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I am new to OOP  ,I had data storage class which need to store temporary data which need for future calculation in a application ,i need to assign different values into this class and return class objects more than one,according to my knowledge there is OOP pattern which i can used for this kind of problem which increase re- usability if some one have have expert in this area please help me to find best pattern for my problem.

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Try to add some commented algorithm to explain your intent.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this is the usage of [Decorator design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern). You can implement participants like this example:

- Component   (LibraryItem)
  defines the interface for objects that can have responsibilities added to them dynamically.
- ConcreteComponent   (Book, Video)
  defines an object to which additional responsibilities can be attached.
- Decorator   (Decorator)
  maintains a reference to a Component object and defines an interface that conforms to Component's interface.
- ConcreteDecorator   (Borrowable)
  adds responsibilities to the component.

Comment: I am sorry actually i don't need to add items into a class at dynamically at run time,i need to create more instance in a same class at run time

Comment: If you considering deep clones, take look at this [stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)